# C# How to get Current URL from Chrome (Multiple language setting)

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I am trying to get current URL from the Chrome browser. My code is working when my browser is in English language. But when someone has a different language it doesn't work due to comparison.

```
AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
AutomationElement elmUrlBar = null;

// elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty,   "Adresse und Suchleiste"));
// if (elmUrlBar != null)
elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));

if (elmUrlBar != null)
{
    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
    if (patterns.Length > 0)
    {
        ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
        objSchemeDetail.ProcessName = val.Current.Value;
    }
}
```

I changed "Address and search bar" into German but it still doesn't work. What is it's replacement?

Comment: It looks like others have the [same](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=271227) problem. You probably have to check the source code for the exact translation.

Comment: I tried but didn't find any source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is a build of Chromium provided by Google. The chromium source code is at [chromium.googlesource.com](https://chromium.googlesource.com/). Searching for "Address and search bar" I found [generated_resources_en-GB.xtb](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/48.0.2564.116/chrome/app/resources/generated_resources_en-GB.xtb) showing the english text with an ID, for example:

```
<translation id="2824775600643448204">Address and search bar</translation>
```

When I search in the German version ([generated_resources_de.xtb](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/48.0.2564.116/chrome/app/resources/generated_resources_de.xtb)) for the same ID, I find

```
<translation id="2824775600643448204">Adress- und Suchleiste</translation>
```

So it looks like you have to check this file for each language you want to support. In chromium version 48 and newer, this text seems to have moved to a different location.